# When to reset the lottery ticket hypothesis algorithm to find initialization?

Tags: neural-network

According to [The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03635.pdf) paper, there are two types of pruning strategies, one-shot pruning, and iterative pruning. Both are explained on page 2. Finding initialization for one-shot pruning is easy because we train the network for `j` iterations and then, reset the weights to the initialization using the obtained mask. What I do not understand is the iterative pruning. On page 2, it says:

> we focus on iterative pruning, which repeatedly trains, prunes, and
>   resets the network over n rounds;

What does `resets the network over n rounds` mean? Does it mean, at each round of pruning we reset the network weights to the initialization using the obtained mask for the current level of pruning? Or it means, we do train and prune the network iteratively without resetting to the initialization, then after `n` levels of pruning, we will reset to the initialization using the last mask we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights are reset to the initial values every time.

The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis relies on the initial weights staying constant. If the starting weights are changed, then the masked subnetwork is no longer effective. So, they must be reset every time.

The authors demonstrated this point experimentally, and summarized on page 5.

> This experiment supports the lottery ticket hypothesis’ emphasis on initialization:
>   the original initialization withstands and benefits from pruning, while the random reinitialization’s performance immediately suffers and diminishes steadily.